# Joining table with large number of entries throws an exception

Tags: java, caching, ignite

I am using Apache Ignite and trying to join multiple caches using an `SqlFieldsQuery`. The exception below is thrown if one of the caches has 2 million records:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to run map query remotely.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.twostep.GridReduceQueryExecutor.query(GridReduceQueryExecutor.java:652)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing$5.iterator(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1119)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.QueryCursorImpl.iterator(QueryCursorImpl.java:98)
    at 

Caused by: javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to execute map query on the node: b72073a8-e58e-4998-9ae5-fc4abf05a800, class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException:Failed to execute SQL query.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.twostep.GridReduceQueryExecutor.fail(GridReduceQueryExecutor.java:278)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.twostep.GridReduceQueryExecutor.onFail(GridReduceQueryExecutor.java:268)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.twostep.GridReduceQueryExecutor.onMessage(GridReduceQueryExecutor.java:249)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.twostep.GridReduceQueryExecutor$2.onMessage(GridReduceQueryExecutor.java:197)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$ArrayListener.onMessage(GridIoManager.java:1915)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1082)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:710)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$1700(GridIoManager.java:102)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$5.run(GridIoManager.java:673)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the log of the node with ID `b72073a8-e58e-4998-9ae5-fc4abf05a800`. There should be an exception that caused the failure.